# wp_get_post_terms not working when using AJAX

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, terms

I am trying to display terms with a load more button on the website, but I have come across a problem while the page loads first the below code works perfectly giving me 4 terms in the correct alphabetic order, but when I pass this argument in ajax it gives me wrong terms. It shows duplicated terms.

**Single Template**

```
<?php

// Get the current post ID
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// Get the taxonomy terms assigned to the current post
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'hotel', array(
   'orderby'   => 'name',
   'order'     => 'DESC',
));

$terms_count = count($terms);

?>

<?php if (!empty($terms)) : ?>
<section class="single-destination-hotels">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell-md-12">
                <?php if (!empty($terms)) : ?>
                    <div class="hotels-list-wrapper">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                            $count = 0;

                            foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>

                                <div class="cell-md-4 cell-lg-3">
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($term)); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php
                                if ($count == 3) break;
                                $count++;
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                        if ($count >= 3) {
                            echo '<div class="load-more-btn-wrap">';
                            echo '<button class="load-more"><span class="icon">';
                            echo __('Load More', 'text_domain');
                            echo '</button>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var loading = false;
            var $loadMoreButton = $('.load-more');
            var $destination_child_pages = $('.hotels-list-wrapper > .row');

            $(".load-more").click(function() {
                var offset = $('.hotels-list-wrapper .cell-md-4.cell-lg-3').length;

                if (!loading) {
                    loading = true;
                    var data = {
                        action: 'load_more_hotels',
                        post_id: <?php echo $post_id; ?>,
                        offset: offset,
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data.response) {
                                $destination_child_pages.append(data.html);

                                var currentoffset = $('.hotels-list-wrapper .cell-md-4.cell-lg-3').length;

                                if (currentoffset >= <?php echo $terms_count; ?>) {
                                    $loadMoreButton.hide();
                                }

                                loading = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<?php endif; ?>
```

**Ajax callback function (Here is the problem terms return is wrong/duplicate)**

```
<?php
function load_more_hotels()
{
    $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $fallback_image = get_field('field_645b5b14b511f', 'option');

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'hotel', array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'offset' => $offset,
    'number' => 4
));

$result = false;
$html = '';

if ($terms) {

    foreach ($terms as $term) :
        $html .= esc_html($term->name);
        $result = true;
    endforeach;
} else {
    $result = false;
}

$msg = array('response' => $result, 'html' => $html);
echo json_encode($msg);

wp_die();
}
 add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_hotels', 'load_more_hotels');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_hotels', 'load_more_hotels');
?>
```